# Oracle SQL mutating table trigger before update

Tags: sql, oracle, triggers, mutating-table, beforeupdate

I want to create an update trigger for a table. The trigger was created, but when I update the column `finish`, it say mutating table.

This is my code

```
    CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER SET_COST BEFORE UPDATE OF finish ON PAY
    FOR EACH ROW

    BEGIN

    UPDATE PAY
    SET PAY.COST = (finish-start) * 20000
    WHERE PAY.ID=:new.ID;

    END;
```

This trigger gives me 'Mutating Table' error and so far I have been unable to fix it. Any Suggestion ? Thanks

Comment: There are literally dozens of answers on StackOverflow about Oracle triggers failing with the mutating table exception. [Why not read some of them???](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=oracle+mutating+table+trigger)

Answer (score 2):

First of all, you shouldn't be doing that at all. There's no use in storing values that are easily calculated whenever you need them.

As of your question: no UPDATE:

```
begin
  :new.cost := (:new.finish - :new.start) * 20000;
end;
```

Comment: very very thanks @Littlefoot, its working, I've tried the same code but I just use =  not := , I must be more careful